# What is the fastest way to zero an existing array?

Tags: c++, arrays, memset

I have an existing 1D array, is `memset` the fastest way to zero it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528590/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-memset-in-c

Comment: Yes, it's the fastest by far. All of the mem... guys are fast because they understand how to set destination words as well as destination bytes. That is, when, for example, four zero bytes are to be moved into a memory word, memset clears the memory location all in one go. As a bonus, memset and memmove and memcopy are portable.

Comment: `memset` will set all the bits to 0 but that may not always be what you want to happen. Do you care about portability? What's in the array?

Comment: may be duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373369/which-is-faster-preferred-memset-or-for-loop-to-zero-out-an-array-of-doubles

Comment: Only if you can't be sure that it's already zeroed.  If you can be sure, `memset` is not fastest.  :)

Comment: A 1 dimensional array of what. **Type is important**.

Comment: @Heffernan, portability is not important. Array is a float array.

Comment: What are you talking about? A "C"-Stale array (float[...])? Or  a C++ vector? It makes a big difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fastest ... probably yes. 
Buggy almost sure!

It mostly depends on the implementation, platform and ... what type the array contains.

In C++ when a variable is defined its constructor is called. When an array is defined, all the array's elements' constructors are called.

Wiping out the memory can be considered "good" only for the cases when the array type is know to have an initial state that can be represented by all zero and for which the default constructor doesn't perform any action.

This is *in general* true for built-in types, but also false for other types.

The safest way is to assign the elements with a default initialized temporary.

```
template<class T, size_t N>
void reset(T* v)
{
    for(size_t i=0; i<N; ++i) 
        v[i] = T();
}
```

Note that, if T is `char`, the function instantiates and translates exactly as `memset`. So it is the same speed, no more no less.

Comment: Platform : Windows, Type: float, Size: 1e6. Also, run-time speed is the first priority, even important than safety.

Comment: @Shilbli: may be the above template can be even better: memset sets bytes. my functions sets floats, that have the same size of a processor word. If the compiler has a good optimization (pacing i in a register and keeping T() as an outside loop constant) may be even faster than a non-specialized memset!
But it mostly depends on the compiler, not the library.

Comment: This can be done with the Standard Library by using `std::fill_n`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: there is a small difference: `std::fill_n` takes the size as a runtime-parameter, here it is a compile-time constant. The compiler can optimize more on this case, for example by unrolling or parallelizing the loop.

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible to know because it's implementation specific. Generally though, `memset` will be the fastest because the library implementers have spent a lot of time optimising it to be very fast, and sometimes the compiler can do optimisations on it that can't be done on hand-rolled implementations because it knows the *meaning* of `memset`.

Comment: Not to mention intrinsics if supported.

Comment: For very large arrays `calloc` may be faster, taking advantage of storage management features of the target machine.  But no way to know without digging into the messy internals.

Comment: @HotLicks he did say "an existing array"

Comment: Yeah, but in C/C++, the definition of "existing array" is fairly broad.

Comment: @HotLicks doesn't `calloc` allocate an array/block of memory?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: "the library implementers have spent a lot of time optimising it to be very fast".

Please ... don't aliment false mith: memset is notjong more tha na loop in machine code. That can be just an instruction is the machine has it. It's not "optimization obtained by programmes with lot of work". It just what the processor is from the time of Mr Federico Faggin.

Comment: @Hot Licks, size of array: 1e6 (a million) float.

Comment: @Shibli -- For a large array using calloc may very well be faster than memset.  To use memset the storage involved must usually be physically cleared, but with calloc the system can (sometimes) allocate the pages and simply mark them to be cleared on first reference, saving all that paging.  (Of course, a reasonably smart system may figure out how to harness the same logic storage management logic for memset; hence you really need to know some low-level implementation details.)  (1MB is probably at about the boundary between the various options.)

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia -- A competent developer of memset will be cognizant of the cache line size of the machine, and may be able to take advantage of "clear cache line" operations, etc.  Generally the front end would clear in a "conventional" fashion up to a cache (or even page) boundary, then there would be a loop using the hardware-specific clear functions, until one gets to the trailing cache/page boundary, at which point "conventional" clearing resumes.